# Apply condition in where statement to all joined elements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I would like to know if there is a way to return something with SQL only if where condition applies to all of the joined element.

For example:

```
Policy.joins(:installments).where("date <= ?" , Time.current)
```

If some policy has 3 installments and one of them has date earlier than Time.current it will return this policy.

I would like to know if there is a simple way to return this policy only if all of its installments are earlier than Time.current?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to use a conditional ActiveRecord association:

```
#app/models/policy.rb
Class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :installments, -> { where "date <= ?", Time.current }
end
```

This will give you the ability to call `@policy.installments`, receiving only the records stipulated in your conditional argument!